# Simple regex replacement

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, so I need your help.
I need to replace 8000 in the string `'"ts";s:4:"8000";s:2:"tr";s:3:"200"'`

```
<?php
$txt = '"ts";s:4:"8000";s:2:"tr";s:3:"200"';
$pattern = '#\"ts\"\;[a-z]{1}\:[0-9]{1}\:\"([0-9]*)#';
$replacement = '7000';
$txt = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$txt);
print($txt);
?>
```

This code outputs `7000";s:2:"tr";s:3:"200"` which isn't what I need.
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just `unserialize()` the data and manipulate the value exactly?

Comment: be aware that if `$replacement` is set to something different than a string of length 4, unserializing this will no longer work. 

Unserializing, changing the unserialized object, serializing it again might be safer than using a regular expression to replace parts of it.

Comment: never used this function before, have to RTM first, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing the *whole* pattern-string with "7000", that's whats wrong. Use grouping:

```
$txt = '"ts";s:4:"8000";s:2:"tr";s:3:"200"';
$pattern = '#(\"ts\"\;[a-z]{1}\:[0-9]{1}\:\")([0-9]*)(\".*)#';
$replacement = '${1}7000${3}';
$txt = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$txt);
print($txt);
```

=> "ts";s:4:"7000";s:2:"tr";s:3:"200"